# R filter dataframe if columns contain string

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

Word of notice: My un-kwnoledge of R is, at least, vast.

I need to filter a dataframe, retaining only those rows that contain a certain string.

What I've tried so far:

```
            DFfilters <- DFfilters  [which  (
                                                    grepl(DFfilters$EMPRESA             ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                                |   grepl(DFfilters$PAIS                ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                                |   grepl(DFfilters$NOMBREOT            ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                                |   grepl(DFfilters$TIPOOBRA            ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                                |   grepl(DFfilters$NOMBRECLI           ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                                |   grepl(DFfilters$Anno_Exp            ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                                |   grepl(DFfilters$pres_descrip_larga  ,input$ExperienciasSearchHidden)
                                            )
                                    ,]
```

Output:

Empty dataframe, even discarding rows that I know that contain 2008 in Anno_Exp.

Also, I get this warning:

```
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$EMPRESA, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$PAIS, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$NOMBREOT, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$TIPOOBRA, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$NOMBRECLI, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$Anno_Exp, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in grepl(DFfilters$pres_descrip_larga, input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I cannot disclose any real data. What I want to achieve is to keep only those rows, if any of the columns in the which() contains a certain string (in the example, I ran input$ExperienciasSearchHidden <- "2008")

Comment: Invert the arguments in all the `grepl`, example - `grepl(input$ExperienciasSearchHidden, DFfilters$EMPRESA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the order in grepl(), put the input first:

```
grepl(input$ExperienciasSearchHidden,   DFfilters$EMPRESA),
# etc..
```

Otherwise it looks ok. Don't really need the `which` in there.

Comment: Indeed, I swaped the args in grepl.... Now it's crashing somewhere else, but at least I got the dataframe filtered. Thank u SO MUCH!